# Setting Eclipse STS to use Java 8 to compile java code of my project

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm very surprised how hard is it to operate Eclipse - almost everything I try to do ends with SE question.

I have a new project which consists of about two files and some external libraries. This project can by compiled manually by a command line script:

```
rem List all java files in jar/ directory to text file
dir /s /B jar\*.java > sources.txt
rem make javac compile those files and put the .class files in bin directory
javac -cp %PZCLASSPATH% -d bin @sources.txt
```

I use java 8 JDK for compiling the project. I am not even dreaming of Eclipse ever building the same way (or building properly at all), but at least I'd like to make it use Java 8 for code validation, as to avoid errors for code incompatible with old java versions:

[image: image description]

I looked into project properties and tried to find something to set-up:

[image: image description]

As you can see, Java 8 is kinda missing in that menu. In NetBeans, I remember just changing the JDK to desired version. Probably better approach than hardcoded menu.

Also the menu doesn't even seem to have much effect, as I see `The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved` error for `import java.util.Arrays;` command:

[image: image description]

So it's not using even the Java 7 now. Note that other projects work fine in the IDE, but this one has been handcrafted so is problematic.

Is there another way of configuring it?

Comment: It also looks like you are using an older version of STS. The latest versions of STS support the Java8 compiler settings already for a long time - independent of the JDK you are running the IDE itself on.

Answer (score 3):

First thing you need to do is make sure that your workspace has access to a Java 8 JRE.

Go to "window >> Preferences". Then type "JRE" in the searchbox. Select "Installed JREs". If no Java 8 is there. Add one.

[image]

Now that Eclipse has a JRE available you can start using it in your projects. You can either set the Java 8 as the 'default JRE' by clicking checkbox in front of it in the same "Installed JREs" prefs dialog, or select it for a specific project (this is really the best as making it the default doesn't guarantee a project will use it, since its only a 'default' used unless a project sets it specifically).

Right click the Project and go to "Properties >> Java Buildpath".

Check the "Libraries" tab shows a "JRE System Library" for Java 8. If it shows a wrong JRE, remove it and add a new one, make sure to select one with the right "Execution Environment" you want to use:

[image]

Normally this should be enough. The compiler target / source levels generally automatically follow the JRE version. Though... it is actually possible to override that. This is because JDK 8 is backwards compatible and capable of compiling and running to Java 7, 6 etc. So the compiler source and target levels are independently configurable.

So... its best to check them and make sure you didn't override the compiler settings by accident. You already have screenshot for that setting so I assume you know where to find it (Project >> Properties >> Java >> Compiler). However, unlike shown in your screenshot, I suggest that you don't set it specifically, but rather select the option to make it follow the selected JRE:

[image]

Final Note: Manually configuring this is indeed a bit painful. People usually don't do that however. If you use maven, for example, then assuming your pom file specifies all the details of how to compile your code and what JRE it requires, then a tool like M2E will configure Eclipse for you, and all that is left for you to do is the first step from my instructions, to ensure that the needed JRE is available to use. M2E will handle all the other steps automatically).